# Querying the length of the biggest stretch of a given character in a text field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can I create a query to find the length of the biggest stretch of a given character in a text field? For example:

```
283948XXXX92388888888X92380XXXX0983XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX45
```

If I wanted the character to be an "8", it would return an integer value of "8"

If I wanted the character to be an "X", it would return an integer value of "18"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Raymosrunerx

PS: I am using putty and remotely accessing a server that has MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier answer is that you don't. You use a scripting language like Python or Perl.

Once you have the string in python you could do something like this:

```
def findLength(str,char):
    count =0
    max = 0
    for ch in str:
        if ch == char:
            count+=1
        else:
            if count > max:
                max = count
            count = 0
    return max

print findLength('283948XXXX92388888888X92380XXXX0983XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX45','X')
```